# Wordpress menu deletes when trying to add a hook

Tags: php, wordpress, hook, action

I'm trying to customize the default Wordpress menus. Added this to my functions.php file and it makes my menus disappear. What is wrong?

```
function custom_novice_menu($args) {
    $defaults = array(
        'container' => 'div'
    );
}

add_action('wp_nav_menu', 'custom_novice_menu');
```

Here is some documentation on [wp_nav_menu()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/)

Answer (score 0):

[wp_nav_menu](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_nav_menu/) is not an action, It is a filter, So you will need to write apply_filters for it and return $nav_menu from the callback function.